# Swift: Init() Pattern for Parent/Child Relationship

Tags: swift, initialization

### Setup

Suppose I have two classes:

```
final class Parent: NSObject 
{
   var child: Child
}


final class Child: NSObject 
{
   weak var parent: Parent?

   init(parent: Parent) 
   {
      self.parent = parent
   }
}
```

---

### Question:

Now suppose that I want to instantiate a `child` and establish this relationship in the `init()` method of `Parent`. I would do this:

```
final class Parent: NSObject 
{
   var child: Child

   init() 
   {
      child = Child.init(parent: self)    // ERROR!
   }
}
```

Swift whines that I'm using `self` before `super.init()`. If I place `super.init()` before I instantiate `child`, Swift whines that `child` isn't assigned a value at the `super.init()` call.

I've been shutting Swift up by using implicitly-unwrapped optionals, like this:

```
final class Parent: NSObject 
{
   var child: Child!

   init() 
   {
      super.init()
      child.init(parent: self)
   }
}
```

My question is: What do people do in this situation? This is/was a VERY common pattern in Objective-C and Swift produces nothing but headaches. I understand that I could de-couple the assignment of `parent` from `Child`'s `init()` so that I could `init()` child, call `super.init()`, and then assign `parent`, but that is not an option in the real-world cases where I run into this. It's also ugly and bloated.

I do realize Swift's intent is to prevent use of an object before it is fully initialized. And that it's possible for `child`'s `init()` to call back to `parent` and access state that isn't set up yet, which becomes a danger with the implicitly-unwrapped optional approach.

I cannot find any guidance about Swift best practice here, so I'm asking how people resolve this chicken-and-egg issue. Is turning properties into implicitly unwrapped optionals really the best way around this limitation? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you inheriting from `NSObject` ?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27163038/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29932292/1187415. In your case that would be `lazy var child = Child(withParent: self)`

Comment: Because, in my non-trivial, real-world cases I'm using classes that inherit from NSObject and the classes need to inherit from something for super.init() to be needed. I've boiled my example down to the very minimum case I can assemble.

Comment: lazy isn't exactly what I want. I want "child" to exist from the beginning of "parent"; I don't want to wait until the first time I go to call "child" to set it up.

Comment: From Joe Groff in a [remotely related discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-define-self-referential-types-with-pointers-which-are-never-nil/33989/11) in the Swift forum: *“IUOs have historically been the answer for handling circular references, .... These days, a property wrapper  ... would probably be the best way to go.”*

Answer (score 0):

You can make it `lazy` and all your headaches will gone!

```
final class Parent {
    lazy var child = Child(parent: self)
}


final class Child {
    weak var parent: Parent?
    
    init(parent: Parent) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
}
```

In Swift, all stored properties should be initialized before `self` is available. Including stored properties in the `superclass`. So Xcode doesn't let you use `self` till then. But using `lazy` means that it **is** initialized before. So you can use `self` freely.

#### Some helpful notes:

1. Don't inherit from `NSObject` if you don't need `objc` advanced features for your class.
2. In swift naming convention, open parentheses `(` will read as `with` in **objective-C**. So you don't need `withParent` as a label in your initializer.
3. Use internal and external naming of arguments as the convention suggests.

<sub>Also note that some of the above notes are written before comments</sub>

Comment: Again, I have good reasons for wanting 'child' to exist when I create it. I do not want it delayed until the first time I call it. For example, the rest of child's "init()" method dispatches an async request to download some data from a remote server. I want that process started immediately. And adding "_ = self.child" to the bottom of parent's "init()" to kick off the lazy property seems stupid.

Comment: The most common case for this is something that has a "init(delegate:)" method. I often want the delegate to be ME and I'm trying to set this up in my own "init()" method.

Comment: Delegate is a `weak` property. You can make parent optional and you are free to use self in the initializer for that. But I don't think that is what you are looking for.